# Check if user login data exists in a table and if not check in another table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Hello! I'm having some trouble making a login for normal users, I have to tables, one is for *admin users* and the other for *employees*. The thing is that I want to use the same login and in the PHP first check if the username exists in the table `admintable` and if not check if it exits in `empTable`.

Here is my code:

It is working and recognizing only admin users but then when I try to log in with employee users it doesn't log in.

THANKS!!

```
<?php

include 'cod/php/utils.php';


if(isset($_POST['txtuser']) )
{
//get data from POST
$txtuser = $_POST['txtuser'];
$txtpass = $_POST['txtpass'];

//verificar que exista el usuario en la tabla de admins
if(exists('admintable', 'Username', $txtuser))
{
    //obtener el password del usuario
    if(get_value('admintable', 'Password', 'Username', $txtuser) == $txtpass)
    {
        //iniciar sesion
        session_start();

        //almacenar el usuario en esta sesion
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $txtuser;          

        header('Location: web/admin.php');
    } 
}
 //verificar que exista el usuario en la tabla de admins
else if(exists('empTable', 'empUsername', $txtuser))
{
    //obtener el password del usuario
    if(get_value('empTable', 'empPassword', 'empUsername', $txtuser) == $txtpass)
    {
        //iniciar sesion
        session_start();

        //almacenar el usuario en esta sesion
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $txtuser;



        header('Location: web/usr.php');
    }
}


    else
    {
        print_login(true);
    }
}
else
{
    print_login(true);
}
else
{
print_login(false);
}
}




function print_login($showerror)
{}
?>
```

Comment: make sure that the `exists` function returns boolean. Also, what is the error message that you are getting?

Comment: `else` is supposed to be mentioned only _once_ for each `if` block.

Comment: You follow the wrong strategy. Don't make two separate queries but a single one against a combined table: you can create a `view` for this once which offers you a "virtual table" holding the (relevant) data of both tables. Then you can simply run your query against that view instead of the two real tables.

Comment: @arkascha you definitely should make an answer from your comment.

Comment: Also, you _never_ should store passwords inside your database tables! No! The way to go is to store a _hash of the password_ and compare that stored hash against a hash generated from the submitted password. That way your uses accounts are protected even if someone gets access to that sensitive data inside the database. This is a pretty good introduction including examples and usable code: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Unfortunately the OP posts next to no details about those two tables. This would mean that an answer alongside my suggestion would have to be written in a very generic manner. This only makes things complex, takes endless time and frankly, I am too lazy for that. ;-)

Comment: Let me agree to disagree, but in the manner for good code design, you should have 2 separate methods i.e. (`isAdmin()` or `exitsInAdminsTable()`) and `isUser()` so -> `if(!isAdmin()) { if(isUser()} { ...`